# Can't retrieve email from FirebaseUser.getProviderData()

Tags: android, firebase, google-plus, firebase-authentication

As the title says, I cannot get the email address of a signed-in user.
I use the multi-accounts system but no matter if the user uses only one or all of the available authentication providers (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Email; all working fine exept for the email-thing). I don't get the email address from any provider.

The only post I found that is somewhat related to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750433/firebase-android-google-plus-login-not-able-to-retrieve-users-email-address). But it's refering an older version of Firebase.

What I did so far:

- using a FirebaseAuth and FirebaseUser instance for every activity
- using a static FirebaseAuth and FirebaseUser instance for all activities

  - didn't make a difference (I will stick to the static thing for now even though a retained fragment would probably be better (from what I read so far))
- deleted all users and signed in again -> no difference
- deleted permission in Google-Account and signed in again -> no difference
- both combined -> no difference
- changed the settings for allowing multiple accounts with one email address in Firebase Console back and forth -> no difference

I don't get any errors, the email object is simply "null".

---

Let's concentrate on one provider for know, I guess the issue is the same for all of them, if not I will go through them one by one.

As it is the easiest to debug I guess I go with Google+:

The Sign-In is happening through a SignInActivity which is extending AppCompatActivity and is getting called by my MainActivity through startActivityForResult().

Here is my Google-Button-Setup:

```
// Configure Google Sign In
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

in the onClickListener I pass these two lines for the Google+-SignIn-Button:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, config.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

My onActivityResult for the Google+-Part:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == config.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult: "+data.toString());
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
        return;
    }
}
```

The handleGoogleSignInResult()-function:

```
private void handleGoogleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: " + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Log.d(TAG,getString(R.string.signed_in_with_google));
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(),null);
        linkAccounts(credential);
    }
}
```

and the linkAccounts()-function:

```
public void linkAccounts(final AuthCredential credential){
    if (config.mFirebaseAuth == null || config.mFirebaseUser == null ){
        config.mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        config.mFirebaseUser = config.mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }

    if (config.mFirebaseUser != null){
        config.mFirebaseUser.linkWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Authentication failed.");

                            try {
                                throw task.getException();
                            } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                //Es ist ein Problem mit den Credentials aufgetreten
                                Log.d(TAG,"Die Credentials haben ein Problem verursacht.");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                                supportFinishAfterTransition();
                            } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                //User existiert bereits in der Datenbank -> kombiniere diesen mit dem neuen Account manuell
                                //Hierfür müssen die Daten des aktuellen Users beim alten, bereits vorhandenen User eingetragen und der aktuelle User abgemeldet werden.
                                Log.d(TAG,"User bereits vorhanden! Daten müssen manuell zusammengeführt werden.");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                mergeExistingAccounts(credential);
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                                supportFinishAfterTransition();
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                mergeExistingAccounts(credential);
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                                supportFinishAfterTransition();
                            }
                        }else{
                            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                            supportFinishAfterTransition();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }else{
        //der User ist "null" -> es ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten
        //TODO: Lösung finden!
        Log.e(TAG, "SignInDialog:linkAccounts(): Der User ist 'null', Accounts können nicht verlinkt werden!");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }

}
```

I cannot get the email on the very first SignIn so `mergeExistingAccounts()` doesn't really come into play, that's why I leave it out for now, it's not complete yet anyways and will only take care of passing some accounts information from an anonymous account to the "re-signed-in" Google+-Account (which was already logged in before a sign out or signed in on another device).

The `onConnectionFailed` is just a debugging thing for now with a "Log.e()"-statement which is not fired.

Sorry for the german comments, it speeds up my development but is less useful for posting problems in here. I guess for future projects I will again stick to english comments for that reason.

Please tell me what other information you may need to help me.

Thanks in advance to everybody!!!

Edit: I just found out that with...

```
acct.getEmail()
```

...in the `handleGoogleSignInResult()` function, I can access the email address. It looks like it's just not passed to the GoogleAuthCredential. :-/

Comment: Good to hear that found your own answer. It's customary in such a case to post it as an actual answer and not an edit to your question.

Comment: Actually that wasn't meant to be the answer, it's just a piece of information that came up during the debugging process. I still can't retrieve the email address through FirebaseUser.getProviderData().getEmail().

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the available provider data this way if firebase user is not showing it:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
List<? extends UserInfo> providerData = firebaseUser.getProviderData();
String email = providerData.get(1).getEmail();
```

`providerData` is a list with more data, at index 1 you'll find the email.

Other data is:

```
providerData.get(1).getDisplayName();
providerData.get(1).getPhoneNumber();
providerData.get(1).getPhotoUrl();
providerData.get(1).getProviderId();
providerData.get(1).getUid();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your provider
when you use google sign in so your provider is google.com, so you can use :

```
firebaseUser.providerData.forEach((element) {
    if(element.providerId.toString() == "google.com" ){
      email = element.email;
    }
  });
```